# Convert an OTU table into binary table for betapart package

Tags: r, binary, lapply

I have an OTU table containing OTU (rows) and sample ID (columns). I am currently trying to first pivot the table so that sample ID becomes rows and OTU becomes columns, and then change the count values into binary values, i.e. 1 for values >0 and 0 for 0 counts, since this is the input for the beta part package.

The OTU table looks like this:

```
> matrix_reprex <- dput(feat_table[1:10, 1:6])
structure(list(ASV = c("457beef2ba139f9db01dc7cd057a3b47", "c50a5f1a3295f6de510ca0f38b425029", 
"1696d13a8d52b779c99f46a5b149ffd6", "b4c065d1250fbbf921a2dd8f60f2f674", 
"98f53519513214e968c569829a1471bb", "197f16f9de1704d0cc2bb2ddd6e9d824", 
"a5b90aeb2ab3b1da1ad0e3f7ab8dd3e4", "f40f36c0d90bd76908e1356820ff892e", 
"026ea702ee6b39a6e7fd00c7b5969d5e", "1a5b67cbf0436cf2b3080464feab291a"
), X1.10A = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0), X1.10B = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), X1.10C = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 26, 0, 
0, 0), X1.11A = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), X1.11B = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

[Exapmle data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXMIC.png)

The expected output would be to have the table transposed and with values larger than 0 as 1, i.e. values 5 and 26 should be replaced by 1.

```
> matrix_reprex_transp <- dput(feat_table2[1:10, 1:6])
structure(list(`457beef2ba139f9db01dc7cd057a3b47` = c("457beef2ba139f9db01dc7cd057a3b47", 
"    0", "    0", "    0", "   0", "   0", "   0", "   0", "   0", 
"   0"), c50a5f1a3295f6de510ca0f38b425029 = c("c50a5f1a3295f6de510ca0f38b425029", 
"    0", "    0", "    0", "   0", "   0", "   0", "   0", "   0", 
"   0"), `1696d13a8d52b779c99f46a5b149ffd6` = c("1696d13a8d52b779c99f46a5b149ffd6", 
"    0", "    0", "    0", "   0", "   0", "   0", "   0", "   0", 
"   0"), b4c065d1250fbbf921a2dd8f60f2f674 = c("b4c065d1250fbbf921a2dd8f60f2f674", 
"    0", "    0", "    0", "   0", "   0", "   0", "   0", "   0", 
"   0"), `98f53519513214e968c569829a1471bb` = c("98f53519513214e968c569829a1471bb", 
"    0", "    0", "    0", "   0", "   0", "   0", "   0", "   0", 
"   0"), `197f16f9de1704d0cc2bb2ddd6e9d824` = c("197f16f9de1704d0cc2bb2ddd6e9d824", 
"    0", "    0", "    0", "   0", "   0", "   0", "   0", "   0", 
"   0")), row.names = c("ASV", "X1.10A", "X1.10B", "X1.10C", 
"X1.11A", "X1.11B", "X1.11C", "X1.12A", "X1.12B", "X1.12C"), class = "data.frame")
```

The code I am using is this one:

```
feat_table2 <- as.data.frame(t(feat_table)) #Transpose table 
colnames(feat_table2) <- feat_table2[1, ] #Make first row into headers 
feat_table3 <- feat_table2[-c(1),] #Delete first row 
str(feat_table3) #Check type of variable in columns 
feat_table3 <- lapply(feat_table3,as.numeric)
feat_table3 <- as.data.frame(feat_table3)
feat_table3_bin <- ifelse(feat_table3>0,1,0)
```

I can successfully pivot the table, convert the first row into headers, and then delete the first row (which is repetition of the header names). But then, when I try to turn the counts into binary values, I am having problems.

I used the lapply function to change the columns into numeric since they were read as characters. Then when I convert the matrix into a data frame, my row names are lost. However, I succeed in making the values binary.

Any idea how to keep my row names? Alternative, any idea how to use a different/more efficient approach?

My session info is:

```
R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Big Sur 11.6

Matrix products: default
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] phyloseq_1.36.0 forcats_0.5.1   stringr_1.4.0   dplyr_1.0.7    
 [5] purrr_0.3.4     readr_2.0.2     tibble_3.1.5    ggplot2_3.3.5  
 [9] tidyverse_1.3.1 tidyr_1.1.4     magrittr_2.0.1  vegan_2.5-7    
[13] lattice_0.20-44 permute_0.9-5   betapart_1.5.4 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
  [1] nlme_3.1-152           bitops_1.0-7           fs_1.5.0              
  [4] usethis_2.0.1          lubridate_1.8.0        devtools_2.4.2        
  [7] httr_1.4.2             rprojroot_2.0.2        GenomeInfoDb_1.28.4   
 [10] backports_1.2.1        tools_4.1.1            utf8_1.2.2            
 [13] R6_2.5.1               DBI_1.1.1              BiocGenerics_0.38.0   
 [16] mgcv_1.8-36            colorspace_2.0-2       rhdf5filters_1.4.0    
 [19] ade4_1.7-18            withr_2.4.2            tidyselect_1.1.1      
 [22] prettyunits_1.1.1      processx_3.5.2         compiler_4.1.1        
 [25] rvest_1.0.1            cli_3.0.1              Biobase_2.52.0        
 [28] xml2_1.3.2             desc_1.4.0             scales_1.1.1          
 [31] callr_3.7.0            XVector_0.32.0         pkgconfig_2.0.3       
 [34] sessioninfo_1.1.1      dbplyr_2.1.1           fastmap_1.1.0         
 [37] itertools_0.1-3        readxl_1.3.1           rlang_0.4.11          
 [40] rstudioapi_0.13        generics_0.1.0         jsonlite_1.7.2        
 [43] RCurl_1.98-1.5         GenomeInfoDbData_1.2.6 biomformat_1.20.0     
 [46] Matrix_1.3-4           Rcpp_1.0.7             munsell_0.5.0         
 [49] S4Vectors_0.30.2       Rhdf5lib_1.14.2        fansi_0.5.0           
 [52] ape_5.5                abind_1.4-5            lifecycle_1.0.1       
 [55] stringi_1.7.5          MASS_7.3-54            zlibbioc_1.38.0       
 [58] rhdf5_2.36.0           pkgbuild_1.2.0         plyr_1.8.6            
 [61] grid_4.1.1             parallel_4.1.1         crayon_1.4.1          
 [64] doSNOW_1.0.19          haven_2.4.3            Biostrings_2.60.2     
 [67] splines_4.1.1          multtest_2.48.0        hms_1.1.1             
 [70] rcdd_1.2-2             ps_1.6.0               pillar_1.6.3          
 [73] igraph_1.2.6           reshape2_1.4.4         codetools_0.2-18      
 [76] stats4_4.1.1           pkgload_1.2.3          fastmatch_1.1-3       
 [79] magic_1.5-9            reprex_2.0.1           picante_1.8.2         
 [82] glue_1.4.2             modelr_0.1.8           data.table_1.14.2     
 [85] remotes_2.4.1          tzdb_0.1.2             vctrs_0.3.8           
 [88] foreach_1.5.1          cellranger_1.1.0       testthat_3.1.0        
 [91] gtable_0.3.0           assertthat_0.2.1       cachem_1.0.6          
 [94] broom_0.7.9            survival_3.2-11        geometry_0.4.5        
 [97] snow_0.4-3             iterators_1.0.13       memoise_2.0.0         
[100] IRanges_2.26.0         cluster_2.1.2          ellipsis_0.3.2
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Thank you for your comment @RonakShah. I have edited the question. I hope now it is clearer what I am struggling with.